# Overwriting existing extension's controller in community

Tags: magento-1.14

I'm trying to overwrite existing extension's controller into my custom extension. As per my understanding I've followed all the steps to do so properly but still I guess I'm missing something. Following are the core references I'm using.

**app\code\community\Mycompany\Mymodule\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <thirdpartymodule>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mycompany_mymodule before="Thirdpartycompany_Thirdpartymodule">Mycompany_Mymodule</mycompany_mymodule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </thirdpartymodule>
         </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app\code\community\Mycompany\Mymodule\controllers\FulfillController.php**

```
require_once 'Thirdpartycompany/Thirdpartymodule/controllers/FulfillController.php';

class Mycompany_Mymodule_FulfillController extends Thirdpartycompany_Thirdpartymodule_FulfillController {

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**app\code\community\Thirdpartycompany\Thirdpartymodule\controllers\FulfillController.php**

```
class Thirdpartycompany_Thirdpartymodule_FulfillController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thirdpartycompany_Thirdpartymodule_FulfillController** extends **Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action** so your scope inside **config.xml** should be **admin** instead of **frontend**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Mycompany_Mymodule>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mycompany_Mymodule>
</modules>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <thirdpartymodule>
            <args>
                <use>admin</use>
                <modules>
                    <mycompany_mymodule before="Thirdpartycompany_Thirdpartymodule">Mycompany_Mymodule</mycompany_mymodule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </thirdpartymodule>
     </routers>
</admin>
```